# How to set MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException duplicate entry 'key' value in table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception

Hi I have user table with 4 columns -userId,userName,emailId,phoneNumber. UserId is primary key and emailId and phone number are unique Keys. when ever i insert duplicate record i get MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException  with message 'Duplicate entry 'name' for key 1' or 'Duplicate entry 'name' for key 2' or 'Duplicate entry 'name' for key 3' etc. How to set these key values to a column. ie 1 for emailId,2 for phoneNumber?

Comment: can you show us the `CREATE TABLE...` DDL, please? Some sample data would help too...

Comment: Hi Tom, here is the DDL:CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `userId` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `emailId` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `phoneNumber` varchar(14) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `loginId` (`loginId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `phoneNumber` (`phoneNumber`),
 )